# Get detailed events from discord

Tags: python, discord

I want to build my own analytics for my discord server. In order to do this is need to get raw event data from a server as detailed as possible.
How can i receive such events as "User open chat/channel" or "User visit server"?

I read the documentation but all what i found is how to get messages and emojis events.